# Error message: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: java, gradle, slf4j

I have a gradle project and I get the following error when I run the application:

```
12:09:28 PM: Executing task 'TestClass.main()'...

> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

> Task :TestClass.main()
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I found couple of questions with the same issue and I tried the solutions.
I have updated the build.gradle file to include the following:

```
testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"
testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:$slf4jVersion"
testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:$slf4jVersion"
testCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:$slf4jVersion"
```

slf4jVersion value is set to '1.7.30'

I checked the project settings -> artifacts and I get the message Nothing to show
[image]

Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: SLF4J is in 2 parts: an API and an implementation. You must add dependency for the API *and* **exactly one implementation**. What you're showing is an attempt to load 3 implementations, and that will fail with a different error message, but only in test mode. The error you do get indicates that you have the API but no implementation, so that's likely in normal mode, i.e. `compile` not `testCompile`. Since you don't seem to understand the choices you have for implementation and how it affects the configuration needs of your application, I highly recommend you **read the SLF4J documentation**.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I had added just one implementation but I couldn't get it to work so I tried adding other implementations. I will take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Update: Adding runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:$slf4jVersion" in build.gradle worked

Answer (score 4):

The most likely reason for this message appearing is that you do not have an *actual* logging library in your classpath.

SLF4J provides a nice abstraction for logging, but it cannot actually log on it's own. Instead, it searches the classpath for compatible loggers and uses them internally. You'll get this warning message if no implementation is available.

The other SLF4J packages you referenced provide compatibility with other libraries your app is using and could possibly be used, but that's probably not what you want to do here.

---

To fix this, fist remove the dependencies except for `slf4j-api` and add a logger implementation to your classpath, e.g. [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/):

```
testRuntimeOnly "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.5"
```

(also note the use of `runtimeOnly` here - the logger is used at runtime but there is no need for it at compile time)

Comment: Thank you for replying, I added the dependencies however, I get the same error. I am new to Java and I feel I am missing something obvious here but not able to figure out.

Comment: Update: Adding runtime "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:$slf4jVersion" in build.gradle worked